# What's the correct offset value for order ASC?

Tags: php, comments

This is my code:

```
$posts_per_page = (int)get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$offset = ($paged - 1) * $posts_per_page;
$args   = array(
    'post_id'       => $post,
    'parent'        => 0,
    'status'        => 'approve',
    'number'        => $posts_per_page,
    'offset'        => $offset,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'order'         => 'ASC'
);

$query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $query->query( $args );
```

I want to appear last 10 comments with order ASC (from bottom to top) with my code it's get yes 10 comments only but not the last comments and i think that's because offset.

what can i do?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, if you remove the offset, does the ASC ordering work?

Comment: @birgire no it's working correct if i remove 'number'        => $posts_per_page,. Hope you can help me on this.

Comment: How are you displaying the comments? If you're not showing them 10 per page (i.e. loading a new page for the next 10) then using `paged` won't work.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Forget about paged, What's the solution to make it working like Instagram comments or Facebook chat? The new is in the bottom and the old in the top? Can you give me a tested example from you?

Comment: One can check the generated query with `echo $query->request;`

Comment: @birgire sorry but i can't understand you can you give me a example for this/

Comment: @trello try adding it after your code example.

Comment: @birgire sorry but it's not working :(